# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'create'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, syntax-error

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Sales
ON
(NAME= Sales_Data,
FILENAME = 'F:\\DB\\Customer DB\\Sales_Data.mdf',
SIZE = 10,
MAXSIZE = 50,
FILEGROWTH = 5)
LOG ON
(NAME = Sales_Log,
FILENAME = 'F:\\DB\\Customer DB\\Sales_Log.ldf',
SIZE = 5,
MAXSIZE= 25,
FILEGROWTH = 5);
GO

USE Sales;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA Sales_schema;
CREATE SCHEMA Production;

USE Sales;
GO

CREATE TABLE Sales.sales.customers
(
    customer_id int,
    first_name varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    email_address varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    phone varchar (15),
    state varchar (15),
    city varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    street varchar (30) NOT NULL,
    zip_code varchar (5) NOT NULL,
 
    CONSTRAINT customers_uq UNIQUE KEY (phone),
    CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Production.categories
(
    category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR (20)
);

CREATE TABLE Production.brands
(
    brand_id INT,
    brand_name VARCHAR (20),

    CONSTRAINT brands_pk PRIMARY KEY (brand_id)
);
```

I expected no errors at all, but I found multiple errors. Please check these unexpected errors

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'create'.
>
> Msg 1801, Level 16, State 3, Line 26
> Database 'SALES' already exists. Choose a different database name.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 46
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 63
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.

Comment: For single quotes inside a string, you need to double them, so `FILENAME= ''F:\...` and I don't think you need to double the backslashes unless you are passing them to another language that requires you to do so. And you do seem to be trying to `CREATE DATABASE Sales` twice, so that shouldn't be shocking. Finally, see the [docs for `CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql), there is no syntax `UNIQUE KEY`. I suggest starting from a working example rather than just making things up as you type...

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP @AaronBertrand , which one is more correct? putting constraints at the end of the block as I did OR defining the constraints "Primary, Unique, etc..." next to their entities from the beginning.

Comment: I like them at the end, but it’s subjective and not “more correct.”

Comment: Great! So I tried your answer and this goes well, but there is one more last error, CREATE SCHEMA  schema_Sales;
CREATE SCHEMA  schema_Production;

 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.      What do you think?

Comment: CREATE SCHEMA has to be in its own batch, so try putting a GO between them. But that won’t work for dynamic SQL, and this is not a very effective format for whack-a-mole debugging. Again, there are hundreds of tutorials out there, you should review some of those instead of just typing and asking “does this work?”